# Slope error from variation of the fitting interval

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have this data that i get using statistics from an arbitrary method. In general this data has almost the same variation as the black curve on the figure.

Analytically i know that this data has a linear growth between the region around t=8~ and t=19~ for this data.

I have a function that calculates the linear fit of any function in a given interval that i can chose. The orange dashed curve is such a fit, here i chose to fit it between t=11.0 and t=14.0, i get a slope (a variable in the legend) that is almost equal to the analytical slope of 3.74e-4.

However if i change the interval i chose a little bit, lets say t=8.0 and t=17.0, i get the green dashed curve. The slope is close to the orange one but is not right.

I need a way to calculate this error/discrepancy on the slope. I tough on calculating all the slopes with al the combinations of intervals, however this is just brute forcing and really long since i have 250 points per 1 time.

Is there such a way? Is there a better way to calculate this? How can i do it?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand your question correctly. But the task does not seem trivial. On the other hand, it would be interesting to solve it analytically. How can this be done? You are trying to approximate functions on some segment with a linear function `y = ax + b` . In general, finding the coefficients of linear regression looks like this [image]
Where `a` is slope and `b` is intercept. `X` looks like this [image] where [image] your values of the variable `t` and [image] values of the dependent variable (black line).
Theoretically, if your `t` values are separated from each other by a constant value [image] You will get an analytical expression of the slope `a` that depends only on the variable `t_0`.
For the sake of practicing linear algebra, you can get this formula, for example, for three values of `t` (you just need to calculate the inverse matrix of size 3x3) and make several matrix multiplications. This will be an explicit dependence of the slope `a` on the interval boundary [image].
But if I were you, I would just calculate the linear regression coefficients as you did for the green line for several intervals and this would allow you to get a rough estimate of what you want.

Comment: Aafter searching an talking. with a professor, i came to the same conclusion. Do linear regression for multiple intervals, then take the largest slope difference and use that as error. Thank you for your time.